# How should we upgrade from AngularJS 1.6.4 to the latest Angular version?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I'm working on a quite large enterprise software application (web-based). We're using Angular 1.6.4 since ... forever. Due to different reasons, we want to / have to upgrade from this old version to a new Angular version. I'm thinking of Angular 8 (?).

First off, I noticed that there is Angular-CLI. Is this the new way to use Angular? I've also found an official [Angular Update guide](https://update.angular.io/#2.0:8.0). But this only ranges from version 2.0 (and we're using 1.6.4).

Due to the size of our application, it will probably take weeks to months to upgrade everything. What is the best way to release this? I disklike on "big" update which moves everything from 1.6.4 to >8.0.

I'm a little bit lost, to be honest. It would be awesome if someone could push me in the right direction. :)

Have a good day!

Comment: This is a really, really, broad question to answer in a Q&A format and unfortunately there's no magic wand approach for your situation. AngularJS and contemporary Angular are very different on so many levels and without knowing a lot of detail around the the application it's difficult to provide much relevant advice at all.

Comment: Very difficult to believe that a *large enterprise software application* would have Angular developers on board who couldn't answer this question. I would go back to management and talk about the hiring practices needed to support such a large enterprise system. I don't mean to offend, but that's a huge failure by management to not be ready for an update an uncountable number of years since Angular 2 came out.

Comment: You could split the application into two, and use page redirects.. but you will break the application :) ..  a good option would be to inject react or vue into the angular application instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to update from Angular 1.x to Angular 2+.

My suggestion would be to check how to create microservices in Angular 2+ (>8.0 in your case) and update the application module by module so as to reduce the errors/conflicts.

Comment: Oh, is it? I didn't know that. I guess I have to continue my research first. Thank you!

Comment: I have not worked much on Angular. But in ReactJS, it is possible to create a MicroService to embed in any other web app (either it is VanillaJS, or some framework/library used). I am pretty sure there will be something similar to that in Angular as well. Happy to help!! :-)